# Hashing google interview

Tags: memory-management, data-structures, hash, string-hashing

> why can't powers of 2 or power's of 10 or prime numbers be good hashing functions? If we want to store overflow records in a hash function, why aren't those good for selection of hashing functions?

Comment: Number by itself is well, a number, not a hashing function. Can you provide more context? Perhaps write a formula for your hashing function?

Comment: I suppose you mean using powers of 2 and 10, and prime numbers as the modulus? gcc's implementation uses prime moduli - the modulus simply keeps increasing in accordance with the required number of buckets.

Comment: Exactly right, as modulus. Why aren't the selection of powers of 2,10 and prime numbers as modulus of hashing functions yield the best memory management results?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your hash function returns a 32-bit unsigned result.  Suppose you choose a modulus of 4096.   What you do is, effectively: `index = hash & 0xFFF` -- so, you throw away the top 20 bits of your hash value.  Now, if your hash is *really* good, and the bottom 12 bits are just as good as the rest, then that's not a problem.  However, if your hash is pretty good over all 32 bits, but the bottom 12 bits are suspect (they might, for example, be more strongly influenced by the last characters of a string)... then you may regret discarding the top 20.  In this case, if you choose any odd modulus, then `index = hash % modulus` the result depends on all 32 bits of the hash.

So, more generally, if your hash is calculated modulo `M`, and your index is taken as `hash % N`, then what you want is for your `M` and `N` to be co-prime.

If `M` is `2^m` (as it usually is), then `N=10^n` is a poor choice, because the bottom `n` bits of the resulting `index` are a straight copy of the bottom `n` bits of the hash.